# cgroups - controlling memory

Tags: cgroups, out-of-memory

I am trying to understand how cgroups and namespaces work. I have been able to get to a point where I can execute example programs in example cgroups and see how the memory resource can be controlled.

I have an example Cgroup with the memory limited to 8MB (memory.limit_in_bytes + memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes). And, I have a simple C program that allocates memory in 1MB chunks. Every time I run this program in the example Cgroup, it gets killed after 3MB is allocated. I am trying to understand why this is the case, when the memory + swap limit is set to 8MB.

Looking at the details memory.stat for this Cgroup, there is a field "total_inactive_anon" that reports a certain number of bytes. When I add that to the 3MB allocated by the program, it sums to just over 7MB. I am wondering whether this is the reason that the program does not get more than 3MB of memory. But, I am not able to fully comprehend what the "total_inactive_anon" accounts for, and whether this is separate from the memory allocated by the program.

If you have any guidance, I would greatly appreciate it.